# Record/Transmit real time video in html5 without MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand the code for the demo chat client at https://appr.tc.
It appears they are able to record video without using MediaRecorder, as there is no mention of MediaRecorder in the code. (See github here: https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc)
If this is the case, what did they use?

Comment: simple answer - See github here: https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc - go through the source code (there's a **lot** of it) to see what they do

Comment: Hi Jaromanda. Thank you for your reply. I'm going through it now, but like you said, there is a lot of code there. I would like to have some some idea of what mechanism they are using. That way, i know in advance if it will work for my project, and exactly what to look for in the code. Thanks

Comment: apprtc only captures video using getUserMedia, it does not record it anywhere. You might find https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/ more useful to look at

Comment: Hi Philipp. It may not "record", but it transmits the video over the Internet to another user in the same chatroom. (which is actually what I am trying to do)
Going through the code, I can see that it uses RTCRTPSender to do this.
Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a wealth of information on this functionality.
Also, if it can broadcast to another user, can it broadcast to a server (maybe red5) who could then save the video for later consumption after the real time session has ended?

Comment: Also, I have tried recording the buffers and sending them, but this only works if the receiver is connected before the first video buffer is sent, which means that a participant who joins late won't get a valid video.

I have also tried recording the video in distinct chunks, each one a valid video. However, playing back the videos in sequence, leaves gaps of a few milliseconds between each complete video, which is terrible from a user experience perspective, especially when it happens every few seconds